# mongoexport not exporting any record from collection

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongoexport

Whats wrong with my command?? It is shows exported 0 records

```
mongoexport --host maint5-w:27017 -u harry12 -p harry12 --db MTLINKi --collection PROGRAM_HISTORY --type csv --fields L1NAME,TIMESPAN --out zips.csv
```

Comment: In general the command syntax looks okay. Please check these anyway. (1) Are there any documents in the collection in the specified database, (2) the output file is created in the directory from where you have run the command, (3) the username and password are verified against an authentication database (as you have not specified, it defaults to the database specified in the --db option); see this [mongoexport username](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html#cmdoption-mongoexport-username).

Comment: mongoexport --host maint5-w:27017 -u harry12 -p harry12 --authenticationDatabase MTLINKi --db MTLINKi --collection PROGRAM_HISTORY --type csv --fields L1NAME,TIMESPAN --out zips.csv

Comment: tried above one same zero exports again

Comment: Can you create a dummy collection with one or two documents in it (within the same database), and export them to a csv?

Comment: I have many other collection in that database but all are zero exports only

Comment: May be you don't have permission to access the data.